# Missing printings from goroutine after closing done channel

Tags: go, channel

I was running the following code based on an example from the book "Concurrency in Go" when I've noticed that not all closing printings in the pipeline are printed.
See that "done multiply!" is missing.
On the other hand, the NumGoroutine() shows only main func is running.
What is wrong with the following code? (https://play.golang.org/p/tkFgvKboVgS)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    generator := func(done <-chan struct{}) <-chan int {
        intStream := make(chan int)
        i:=0
        go func() {
            defer close(intStream)
            for {
                select {
                case <-done:
                    fmt.Println("done generator!")
                    return
                case intStream <- i:
                    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
                    i++
                }
                fmt.Println("generator after select")
            }
        }()
        return intStream
    }

    multiply := func(
        done <-chan struct{},
        intStream <-chan int,
        multiplier int,
    ) <-chan int {
        multipliedStream := make(chan int)
        go func() {
            defer close(multipliedStream)
            for i := range intStream {
                select {
                case <-done:
                    fmt.Println("done multiply !")
                    return
                case multipliedStream <- i * multiplier:
                }
                fmt.Println("multiply after select")
            }
        }()
        return multipliedStream
    }
    add := func(
        done <-chan struct{},
        intStream <-chan int,
        additive int,
    ) <-chan int {
        addedStream := make(chan int)
        go func() {
            defer close(addedStream)
            for i := range intStream {
                select {
                case <-done:
                    fmt.Println("done add !")
                    return
                case addedStream <- i + additive:
                }
                fmt.Println("add after select")
            }
        }()
        return addedStream
    }

    done := make(chan struct{})

    intStream := generator(done)
    pipeline := add(done, multiply(done, intStream, 2), 2)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        close(done)
        fmt.Println("Closed done")
    }()
    for v := range pipeline {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    fmt.Println("finished iterating pipeline")
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("ramaining goroutines:", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    fmt.Println("finished!")
}
```

Output:

```
add after select
2
multiply after select
generator after select
multiply after select
add after select
4
generator after select
multiply after select
add after select
6
generator after select
Closed done
multiply after select
done add !
finished iterating pipeline
generator after select
done generator!
ramaining goroutines: 1
finished!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are code paths that will not print some of the `done` messages. The scheduler happened to choose one that does not print the one for `multiply`. If you change the code a bit (for instance, log at different instances than you're doing now), you'll see that it may miss the `add` `done` message as well. (https://play.golang.org/p/meEPM5GR9Rr). Here's the reason:

If the `done` message arrives right after generator writes the number to the channel and the multiplier reads it, then the multipler sees that `done` is available and picks that. This is the case when `multiplier` prints the `done` message. If the `done` message arrives while multiplier is waiting in the for-loop, then multiplier will receive the closing on the input channel (not the `done` channel), causing the for loop to terminate without printing the `done` message.

The problem arises because you're reading from a channel in a for-loop, and then selecting. While waiting for the for-loop to read from the channel, none of the events related to the select is evaluated.

A better way of dealing with this is not using a for-loop to read from the channel. For instance:

```
for {
     select {
        case <-done:
           return
        case i, ok:= <-intstream:
           if !ok {
              return
           }
           select {
               case <- done:
                    return
               case addedStream <- i + additive:
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` and `multiply` routines are not forever loops, but rather `for ... range` loops.  As such, at the top of each loop, they wait for the next integer, rather than waiting in the `select` that either receives the close from `done` or sends a result to their stream.  This is not a *problem*, but it means that if their input stream is *closed*, they will return without entering the loop itself.

If I [add `fmt.Println` calls to expose the point at which they exit due to reaching the end of their input stream](https://play.golang.org/p/QyMHbXCRdKU), the behavior changes slightly (probably due to timing; I haven't bothered to reason much about it and [Burak Serdar posted his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59523188/1256452) already while I was typing this) and the output becomes:

```
add after select
2
multiply after select
generator after select
multiply after select
add after select
4
generator after select
multiply after select
add after select
6
generator after select
Closed done
done multiply !
add got end of stream - done!
finished iterating pipeline
generator after select
done generator!
ramaining goroutines: 1
finished!
```

It's often more reasonable to make *only* the generator itself take a `done` signal, and make the pipelined functions always write all their results, which makes them more predictable.  Of course then whoever is reading each pipe must read to the end—but you do that already in the main goroutine, so we just propagate this throughout.  [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/MbYnvjF9hPx) is a simplified version of your code that does it this way; it outputs:

```
2
generator after select
4
generator after select
6
generator after select
Closed done
8
generator after select
done generator!
multiply got end of stream - done!
add got end of stream - done!
finished iterating pipeline
remaining goroutines: 1
```

Note that this time, we get the final computed value (8) from the final generated value (3).